# Creepy Unknown Guest User

Tags: passwords, user

I have two guest user accounts on my computer: one that is normal and one that is not supposed to be there. I didn't create it and it has a password that I don't know and I can't get into it or delete it. I go into my user settings as the administrator and it's not there. It doesn't show up so I can't remove it. It also has a really creepy picture. It has the normal guest user icon but it has green static bars covering it. It's like it a hacker or something. I just want to get rid of it; it creeps me out. What can I do?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello Gavin, Although I suspect I know the issue from prior experience, it would help us a lot if you vou could add some details like which operating system you're using and maybe even at a few screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

The following process would work on Windows 7 and 10:

1. Press Windows button + R
2. type `netplwiz`
3. Go to the "Advanced" tab and click the "Advanced" button.
4. You should get the user management console, click the "Users" folder, here you can press the right mouse button on users to delete or disable their accounts.

Comment: I should note that this answer is only applicable on Windows systems.